# What is the meaning of 'Un mensaje hay entre líneas'?

Tags: significado

> Un mensaje hay entre líneas

Best translation I could find is "a message between the lines".

Then I saw in the YouTube comments section where someone (perhaps from a native speaker) had besmirched this translation.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly that.

Comment: @Gorpik Hmm. So whoever that was in the YouTube comments section that spoke badly about this translation was merely being rude.

Comment: From "Jarabe de Palo"?

Comment: @fedorqui  Yes. You sure do know your music!

Comment: I would say so, yes. This expression is more or less the same in Spanish as in English. Or maybe the commenter's English is not too good, though he thinks it is :)

Comment: "To read between the lines, that lead between the lines, that lead me to you" (Alan Parsons Project, The eagle will rise again)

http://www.lyricsfreak.com/a/alan+parsons+project/the+eagle+will+rise+again_20005367.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La expresión (o metáfora) que más se suele usar es la de "**leer entre líneas**" (*reading between the lines*).

El significado de leer entre líneas es la de leer cuidadosamente o con más énfasis una parte del párrafo que puede contener información oculta o solapada, es decir, vuelve a leer este párrafo que hay más información de la que aparentemente hay.

Otro significado es que sepas interpretar un mensaje que te sea dado de forma indirecta, para que otros receptores no sepan el verdadero significado que la propia frase conlleva.